# Calling a method every certain time and stop calling it on a certain condition in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a method called check in my Java class in Android and I  call it every 30 seconds using the following method . My problem is that I want to stop calling it when a variable called `stopFlag` is equal to 1 but I'm unable to do that using `timer.cancel()`.

Here is my method:

```
 public void callAsynchronousTask() 
{
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            check(currentDistance);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        if( stopFlag==1){
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            return;
        }
        else
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 30000); //execute in every 30000 ms
    }
```

// check method

```
public void check(double oldDistance)
    {
        currentDistance=measureDistance(myLoc.getLatitude(),myLoc.getLongitude(),RetrieveStationId.getStation_lat(),RetrieveStationId.getStation_lon());
        if(currentDistance>=0 && currentDistance <200)
        {
            Log.e("Diff",Double.toString(oldDistance-currentDistance));
            joined=0;
            Join.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button);

            StateListDrawable drawable = (StateListDrawable) Join.getBackground();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(238,238,238),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            updateMarker();updateCamera();
            stopFlag=1;
        }
        else if(oldDistance-currentDistance>0)
        {
            Log.e("Diff",Double.toString(oldDistance-currentDistance));
            joined=1;
            Join.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button);

            StateListDrawable drawable = (StateListDrawable) Join.getBackground();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(100,100,100),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }
        UpdateLocation updateLocation = new UpdateLocation(this);
        updateLocation.execute(latitude, longitude,iden,Integer.toString(request),destination,Integer.toString(joined));
        updateMarker();
        updateCamera();

    }
```

Comment: Did you forget to set `stopFlag` to 1? If you want help you need to post [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your question is not complete as you don't show where you modify the value of `stopFlag`

Comment: You can use Android Jov to achieve the same thing !

Comment: what is Android Jov ? Mohamed

Comment: I set the stop flag in the check method  I added it

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.